# How can I create locale-sensitive new global date styles, or modify the existing ones?

Tags: actionscript-3, datetime, apache-flex, localization, flex4.5

I'm using a `DateTimeFormatter`, like this:

```
        var dateFormatter:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter();
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateTimeStyle.SHORT;
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateTimeStyle.SHORT;
```

And I'm ensuring it uses the system locale with this:

```
        setStyle( "locale", LocaleID.DEFAULT );
```

This works ok, and I see different formats when I switch my system's regional settings.

The problem is that the "short" US time format is like "8:01 PM". We are constrained for space, so I need to change this to a 24-hour format, ie "20:01".

Similarly for the dates, there are places where we would like to omit the year - "11 Jan" - or the day of the month - "Mar 2013".

Ideally, we would like to define custom global date styles, instead of just using the built-in `SHORT`, `MEDIUM`, `LONG`. But just being able to modify those ones would be ok too.

Comment: I've discovered that it actually uses the date and time formats from the system settings. They are not configurable via resource properties.

Answer (score 0):

The formats come from the system settings, not from properties files. In order to have the format be locale-dependent and also customisable, you have to create your own DateFormatter implementation. With that, you can hook into `ResourceManager` to request different format patterns for the current locale.